# How to fix when riggin the surface is not smooth?

Tags: rigging

I am rigging my character and when I do the surface becomes all pixelated. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: it seems that your model has not been set as "smooth" shading, but is in the default "flat" shading mode. This can also be driven by the autosmoothing feature (see the "object data" properies panel), if set.

Comment: @m.ardito i still get the same problem but a smoother version

Comment: if you can share the .blend (eg: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) I'll take a look.